# Do I have to delete my project in order to check it out of svn?

Tags: svn

This is my first ever attempt at creating an svn repository and I'm confused.

I have a project in `/var/www/project`, and I have a `/var/svn/` dir to store the repositories, so I run:

```
$ svnadmin create /var/svn/project
```

and I import my tree with

```
$ svn import /var/www/project file:///var/svn/project/trunk
```

so far so good -- I think

Now I need a working copy, but I can't checkout in my existing dir or I get

```
svn: Failed to add file 'some.file': an unversioned file of the same name already exists
```

am I supposed to delete the entire project tree and then check it out of svn? Also, is this the right way to set up a repository?

Comment: What command do you use to check out?

Comment: Have you tried making a code change and committing the changes yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can rename the original project directory if you feel unsure,
then check out to a new dir

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do as well, or just check it out under a different name.

Comment: Accepting this answer since I like to be super careful when doing this sort of things, but thanks to Michael Hackner for pointing out the `--force` option too

Comment: This option is unideal when your project's checkout takes over a day.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
svn checkout --force file:///var/svn/project/trunk /var/www/project
```

This will allow you to checkout into your existing directory that you just imported from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you import a project to a repository, you [have to perform a check out](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import):

> Note that after the import is finished, the original tree is not converted into a working copy. To start working, you still need to svn checkout a fresh working copy of the tree.

Be sure not to erase your original code to early, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out to a new directory. You can always rename it later once you're sure.